# Unpacking dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following program gives error **unexpected keyword argument 'John'**

```
def fn(a,b):    
    
    print(a, b)

emp = {'John':1, 'David':2}
fn(**emp)
```

It only works if keys of the dictionary are 'a' and 'b'.

I expected it to print 1 and 2

Comment: Because those are the names of the function's arguments. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `**emp` will be `John = 1, David = 2` when you pass it to this argument.

Comment: `fn(*emp)` writes `John Davis` , what result you wanted ?

Comment: You could change the definition of fn to accept any number of named arguments using `def fn(**kwargs):`

Comment: In order to help you we need to understand what you were trying to achieve and what is your expected behavior

Comment: I expected it to print 1 and 2

Comment: @John so look at the answer giving the result you want (and accept it ofc)

Comment: @John please also edit your answer to indicate the result you wanted (allowing to reopen it)

Comment: @bruno I will add this to the question and then vote to reopen. It would have been nice to have allowed the OP a little time to clarify this before closing.

Comment: Okay, OP has already edited the question. Voting to reopen as-is.

Comment: @alaniwi I don't completely agree. To me the problem is not just **what** is the expected output, but also **why**. It is still not clear exactly what OP is trying to do with the dict if he just wants to print 1, 2. I am missing a clear problem statement, like: "How to print all dict values in one line". That would make it clear

Comment: @Tomerikoo there are two questions, first one asking why that result, and 'under' it how to get the expected result, when OP says "expected it to print 1 and 2" that makes the second clear enough

Comment: Behind my vote to reopen is that there is more useful stuff that can be said here --  beyond the one answer that has been posted before it got closed -- about whether one can or cannot rely on a particular ordering of arguments after unpacking in this way, depending which version of Python is used. I would have posted something about that, but the question was closed just too early, and I am not now going to have time to do so. Hopefully if it does get reopened, somebody else can post an answer that expands on this point.

Comment: @alaniwi you can also put a remark on the existing answer to help Buffer to improve his answer

Comment: @alaniwi *this way* you mean in the OP or answer? In the OP there is no problem with ordering. If it is the answer you are talking about, it should be a comment in/to the answer, not a new answer. And this is exactly my point. We can't know if ordering is even an issue here without more details...

Comment: Well if a question is closed that is saying that it is not worthy of being answered, so it seems a little odd to say let's keep it closed but take advantage of the fact that an answer in fact got posted earlier. Anyway, potentially there *is* a problem if the OP expects to unpack dictionary values in a particular order, and that is an issue related to the question itself. But anyway, I'm going to leave it there as about to have to do other stuff.

Comment: @alaniwi what I meant is that unpacking with `**kwargs` as no potential issues with order. which is what is used in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code

```
emp = {'John':1, 'David':2}
fn(**emp)
```

is the equivalent of `fn(John=1, David=2)`. It works when it is set to `a` and `b` because those are the names of your arguments. Now I am guessing you want to unpack the values from the dict. You can do it like this

```
emp = {'John':1, 'David':2}
fn(*emp.values())
```

also note that if the only thing the function `fn` does is pass the values to `print` then there is no real reason to have it as you can easily just do this

```
print(*emp.values())
```

Comment: @John Please note that unpacking this way (`*emp.values()`) might be implementation-dependent regarding the order. From Python 3.7 dicts are insertion-ordered so it will print 1, 2. For earlier versions the order might change...

Comment: @Tomerikoo you can submit an edit to the answer if you want, I will accept it

Comment: @Tomerikoo  yes, I know from Python 3.7, dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order